# Block editor not recognizing markdown

Tags: block-editor, markdown

I'm under the impression that I should be able to paste Markdown text into the block editor and that it should pick that up and convert it as per: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/blocks/src/api/raw-handling

But that does not work.

In my example I have some text that's like this:

```
> bq1

> bq2
```

I would expect that copy pasting that into the editor would result in two quote blocks being created. At the moment the markdown syntax is not interpreted at all. This is the same for headings etc.

Is this standard behaviour? Is there some other way to be able to paste formatted text into the editor?

Comment: are you trying to paste it into a HTML/code view? Or a paragraph block? What's the specific markdown flavour you're working with? If I copy paste markdown from a view source github it shows up as preformatted text, but that has nothing to do with markdown itself but source formatting, shift + cmd + v pastes just the text which is interpreted as markdown just fine. If not, can you be more specific than "does not work"? If it does not do what you expected, what does it do instead?

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: if it's not being interpreted as markdown, what is it being interpreted as? That is still unclear. Also did you see my comment about copy pasting with formatting? I don't think this is a developer/coding question, this looks like a user support question, and most likely user error. It's very probably that you're copy pasting with formatting and it's interpreting it not as markdown, but as formatted code, and that cmd+shift+v would fix the problem. cmd+v gives me a code block with the 2 quotes because I copied it from a code block in your Q, cmd+shift+v gives me a block quote

Comment: OK. You're right, if I paste and match, then it creates a single quote block. Still my expected behaviour would be for it to create 2 quote blocks.

Comment: Also the developer question is that this feature is totally undocumented and it's unclear where to get help or file a bug if even.

Comment: either on the gutenberg github repo or on WP Trac, if it impacts a currently released WordPress version then it's no different to any other bug in WordPress, exactly the same process applies